# sp_send_dbmail: avoid (n rows affected)

Tags: sp-send-dbmail, rows-affected

Calling sp_send_dbmail: successful execution, but at the ends appear an extra line with rows affected by the query.

Is there any way to avoid thiks line?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Instead of creating new tags, please see if you can use existing tag. This will make your question more clear

Comment: Add "set nocount on" before the call to sp_send_dbmail

Answer (score 4):

What cgsabari says is true but incomplete. You need to set `NOCOUNT` in the query you are passing to `@query` parameter. Otherwise it won't work

Answer (score 2):

Try the below query

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
--some queries
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

It avoids the row(s) affected message.